# Kohana ORM поиск

Tags: orm, kohana

Здравствуйте ,нужно осуществить поиск по нескольким полям и таблицам. Есть модель Feedback_theme в ней прописаны связи ,все вроде как работает но работает некорректно не выполняются условия ,и в выборку попадают все элементы из базы
    // Поисковый запрос
        $query = ORM::factory('Feedback_Theme');
        $query->or_where_open();

```
        if (!empty($data['title'])) {
        $query->where('title','LIKE',$data['title'].'%');
        } else {
        $query->where('title','LIKE',$data['title']);
        }

        if (isset($data['category_id']) && $data['category_id']>0) {
            $query->or_where('category_id','=',$data['category_id']);
        }

        if (!empty($data['content'])) {
        $query->feedback->or_where('content','LIKE',$data['content'].'%');
        }

        if (!empty($data['status'])) {
        $query->or_where('status','=',$data['status']);
        }

        $query->or_where_close();

        $messages_count=$query->count_all();
        $pagination = Pagination::factory(array('total_items' => $messages_count));
        $pagination->route_params(array('controller' => $this->request->controller(), 'action' => $this->request->action()));

        $messages = $query->limit($pagination->items_per_page)->offset($pagination->offset)->find_all();

        $this->template->content=View::factory('feedback/searchlist')
            ->bind('messages',$messages)
            ->bind('pagination',$pagination);
```

Почему так происходит пока не могу ,голова уже плохо работает (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

метод `count_all()` в kohana сбрасывает полученную модель. Я его немного дописал, добавив параметр

```
count_all($reset = true)
```

и перед строчкой, которая возвращает результат:

> if($reset)
>     {
>
> ```
> $this->reset();
>
> }
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Лучше наверно не переписывать встроенные компоненты Коханы, ибо их используют и модули.
Чтобы модель не сбрасывалась, перед count_all() надо писать

```
$model->where()->....->where()->reset(FALSE)->count_all();
```

Аналогично можно поступать и с find_all().

Comment: а об этом методе не знал. Спасибо!